# Can't redirect to another page using php

Tags: php

This is the trouble-making code:

```
<?php
//some code here
$zone = 'op';
$url = 'thread-list.php?zone=$zone';
header('Location : '.$url);
?>
```

Everything before and after header is working fine but the page is not getting redirected! What should I do?
 Using Header is working fine on other pages except here!

Comment: Any output before the `header()` call? Make sure there isn't.

Comment: Any errors? On page, in error log, ...? Note: Variables in single quotes aren't executed, you will have dollar sign in URL.

Comment: No error on the php page! @panther

Comment: that is not possible that you are not being redirected and no error message also, then i think you need to turn on your error reporting use the function `ini_set('display_errors','on')` at the start of the code.

Comment: There are some outputs before the header call, I put them there for debugging @jeroen Let me try removing them!

Comment: I had errors flashed for other misakes but none for this one! Let me try your error reporter! @Sourabh

Comment: No luck! @Sourabh with `ini_set('display_errors','on')`

Comment: the problem seems to be with `//some code here` make sure there is nothing echoed from that part of code

Comment: Guys I had declared $url with single inverted commas.... I changed i to doubles and it worked.. Thanks! @Sourabh

Comment: Guys I had declared $url with single inverted commas.... I changed i to doubles and it worked.. Thanks! @panther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either:

```
header("Location: " . $url);
```

or

```
header("Location: $url");
(double quotes evaluate the content)
```

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: it worked when I used used " instead of ' while declaing $url. Thanks

Comment: **Note:** If you have output before the `header()` call, use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

There should be no space between "location" and ":"

```
$url='http://google.com' ;
 header("location: $url");
```

OR

```
header("Location: ".$url);
```

Also

```
    $url = 'thread-list.php?zone=$zone';
```

Here `$zone` is error It will not print the value of `$zone`

Comment: there should be no space between "location" and ":"

Comment: Its done! I should've used " instead of ' while declaring $url. Thanks for the efforts though!

Comment: That was what I was doing! It wasn't working with the single inverted commas but it worked with the Doubles!